# Algorithm for calculating result of multi-choice quiz

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm struggling with the edge cases of an algorithm for calculating the result of an A, B, C style quiz.

The quiz is made up of an arbitrary number of questions, each having exactly 3 answers corresponding to A, B and C. Each question is displayed on its own with a continue button, once all questions have been answered the result is displayed.

There are 3 possible results, corresponding to A, B and C.

The result displayed should be the answer chosen the most.

If two answers were chosen equally, the result should be which of those answers was chosen last.

It's the final part that I'm struggling with, what's the best way to calculate this and what do I need to store during the quiz to do so?

The initial calculation I have is:

```
if (countA > countB && countA > countC)
{
    result = "A";
}
else if (countB > countA && countB > countC)
{
    result = "B";
}
else if (countC > countA && countC > countB)
{
    result = "C";
}
else
{
    // two results are equal
}
```

What's the best way to calculate the last case?

Comment: Chosen last by time? So in the case of a draw, if countA == countB then countB is displayed if the last answer was B? If so then just look for the last result of the tied result (trivial to do in your SQL query).

Comment: @James yes, however the last answer could be C so I need to know the last answer out of A or B. This isn't stored in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store all activity (selecting the answers) in a list-like data structure. If the answer is selected you add it to the list, otherwise, you simply remove it from the list. When calculating the last case, go from the back of the list and look for either one of the equally weighted results. The first that is found, was chosen last. Since it was chosen last, it is the result.

Using this method, you could also count all options (A, B and C) by simply counting the occurrences of the options in the list.

Comment: I was already storing the answers in a list and counting them this way, it just hadn't occurred to me that I could also iterate back through the list :)

Answer (score 3):

The question you posed does not seem to take into account whether the answer is correct or not.  Either way, you can keep 7 counters:

- Number of answers, A (or correct A answers)
- Number of answers, B
- Number of answers, C
- Current question index (for use in next three counters)
- Index of last answer, A (or last correct A answer)
- Index of last answer, B
- Index of last answer, C

For each question, you increment the "Current question index".  If you care if the answer is correct, only do the following steps when it is correct.  If you don't care, always do the following steps.

If the answer A is given, increment the "Number of answers, A" counter, and set the value of "Index of last answer, A".

When you hit the end of your quiz, you will have plenty of data to construct the correct response.

Comment: There is no concept of a correct answer, I should of been clearer that only one can be chosen per question. This is a good solution, however the other answer fit better with the constraints of my situation.

Comment: @roryf: They answered first, and correctly, so it is fine with me if you award them the answer :)  Which constraint in your question did my answer violate?  Or did their solution just jive better with how you have your app structured?

Comment: you didn't violate any constraints, I deliberately left it open to allow more generic answers. As you say, it just fit better with my application.

Answer (score 0):

An idea might be to introduce an array or 3 ints, each element corresponding to A, B or C. I assume each question has a number. Each time a question is answered you store the question number in that array. Then you just need to iterate over the array and look which element has the highest number, i.e. was given last.

Comment: And what if two elements have the same value?

Comment: That wouldn't be possible, except if you can give two answer to a question at the same time. In the proposed array, you don't store how often an answer was given but at what question number that answer was used last.